# How to match a list of numbers to another file with a list of numbers?

Tags: ruby

I have a list of numbers :

```
Line 1
6728
2882
18181

Line 2 
282828
4778
2876
9393

Line 3
73920
2489

Line 4
53689
8292
93838
```

To match to the list of the line number:

```
4
7
35
52
98
148
406
```

I have tried to read both the file and compare it but comes out error :

> no such file or directory - 4

```
inc = 'incoming.txt'
grid = 'Lines.txt'

File.readlines(inc).each do |a|
  File.readlines(grid).each do |line|
   if grid == a
      puts line
    end
  end
end
```

Expected result:

```
Line 4
53689
8292
93838

Line 7
6272
4441
98754

Line 35
156
4785
9867
14286
986
```

Comment: It is absolutely unclear how the expected result is got.

Comment: the first file contain the line number with the numbers. the second file consist of list of line number only. I wanted to filter the line number in the first file according to the second file list number.

Comment: So the correct expected result from the input you’ve showed would be _only_ `Line 4`?

Comment: I assume you want to extract lines 4, 7, 35 and so on from a file, but you've only shown lines 1-4. Examples should be complete so readers can demonstrate how their code works. For example, show lines 1-10 and select, say `desired_lines = [0,2,4,5,8]`, where lines are indexed beginning at zero. Also, rather than showing what the file looks like, make it the string one would read from the file with `str = File.read(<filename>)`, say, `str = "6728 2882 18181\n282828 4778 2876 9393\n..."` (but no ...). Also, always show the desired result of an example as a valid Ruby object.

Answer (score 0):

With a help of regular expression that would be possible.

```
lines = File.read('Lines.txt').split
input = File.read('incoming.txt')

lines.map do |l|
  # select everything starting with Line NN
  #   till the empty line _or_ EOF
  input[/Line #{l}.*?(?=\n\s*\n|\z)/m]
end.compact.join($/)
```

---

Also, there is a flip-flop solution :)

```
File.readlines('incoming.txt').select do |l|
  true if lines.include?(l[/(?<=Line )\d+/])..(l =~ /^\s*$/)
end.join($/)
```

More about [flip-flop](http://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2018/02/22/flip-flop-real-application).